# Copying Time Machine backup to another location

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I made a Time Machine backup to an external drive.  When I select the ".backupdb" folder on that drive in Finder and copy it to another location, the destination is much smaller than the source.  Get Info in Finder tells me the source is 374GB, and the destination is 61GB.

Is that just a strange effect of Time Machine's multiple versioned copies, or is Finder actually only copying a portion of my files?  The Finder copy operation completes without any errors or user intervention.

Comment: I'm afraid a simple copy/paste won't do. Have you tried if the TM volume is recognized and works after that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating Time Machine Volumes](http://superuser.com/questions/112007/migrating-time-machine-volumes), if that's what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score -1):

Well I imagine you can use software to carbon copy the drives, as long as the destination drive has at least the same capacity as your current drive.